# Overriding css variables in ionic 4

Tags: angular, sass, ionic4

I am trying to override css variables to change apperance of **ion-segment-button** element in a page of my ionic 4 application.

I tried the to uses the variables specified in this page : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment-button

Here is a code excerpt of the page.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="tertiary">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title align="center">Preferences</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-segment>
        <ion-segment-button value="categories">
            <ion-label>Categories</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="pays">
            <ion-label>Countriess</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="langues">
            <ion-label>Languages</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-content>
```

If for exemple i want to customize the padding top of the ion-segment-button of my page, according to the docs available here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment-button, **--padding-top** is the name of the variable used to do it, so i opened the sass file of the page containing **ion-segment** and i added the following code :

```
ion-segment-button{
    --padding-top:3px;
}
```

But it do not work.

It is just an exemple, i have many others properties that i want to customize using ionic 4 sass variables, but i think that the method i use to do it is wrong.

Any hep ?

Comment: could it be the typo in your CSS selector? sengment should be segment.

Comment: It was a mistake, i edited the post and the code but it do not work.

Comment: can you tell me the name of the HTML file and name of the CSS file? (Full name with extension)?

Comment: the html file is named **preferences.page.html** and the scss file is named **preferences.page.scss**

Comment: can you create a plunker